# How can I access the nodes in the fxml file in order to handle their events?

Tags: event-handling, javafx-2

i have a fxml file(I created the file using scene builder), and i wanna handle, say, the mouseEvent for a button. how can i do that?? and is there a way to handle the event in the scene builder itself??

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can specify action for mouse event in Scenebuilder itself , go to Inspector Panel -> Code panel .

> The Code panel enables you to specify the action that should be taken
>   when a drag-and-drop, keyboard, mouse, or any other event occurs on
>   the selected element.

[image]

Reference :
[Scene Builder Inspector panel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/inspector-panel.htm)

Comment: But the menus for each event are empty, the only option on them is empty! how should i write the code for that?

Comment: hmm , define a control for your FXML and link your controller to FXML file and then you can assign methods in controller to events!. here is simple FXML tutorial hope it will give some idea http://www.e-zest.net/blog/javafx-2-x-development-using-fxml/